# When will one maximum turn into three maximums?

Tags: probability

If $y =e^{-(x+k)^2} + e^{-(x-k)^2} + e^{-x^2}$ for some constant k,

then y is the sum of three normal distributions, with means 0, k and -k.  If k is small, y will have one maximum at x=0.

If k is large enough, the graph of y will be 3 maximums.  What value of k is required for there to be three distinct maximums?

Comment: Experimenting with Wolfram Alpha I found that he value of $k$ is between $1.458$ and $1.459$, but I've not an analytical solution.

Comment: To me, the problem is : what do you exactly mean by *distinct* ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, by distinct, I mean when there exists three maximum solutions to the equation y'(x) = 0, as opposed to x = 0 being the only such solution.

Comment: It  *seems* that it is about $k=\sqrt 2$

Comment: I was not too bad with $k=\sqrt 2$ since the answer you received gives  $k \gt \sqrt{\log \left(e^2-1\right)}\approx 1.36183$